# MySQL WHERE end as column name 'unknown'

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL query.

```
SELECT 
p.`id` as id, 
p.`postinguser` as postinguser,
p.`page` as page,
p.`likedby` as likedby,
p.`redwabled` as redwabled,
case r.`redwabledby`
when '5' then r.`time`
else p.`time`
end as date_time 
FROM `uc_posts` p left join `uc_redwables` r on p.id = r.dwable
WHERE (p.`postinguser` = '5' OR find_in_set('5',p.`redwabled`)) AND (p.`time` < '2016-08-19 12:31:12') order by date_time desc LIMIT 20
```

This collates information from two different tables and returns the following batch of results:

[image]

My problem is I want to change the `WHERE` query line to:

```
WHERE (p.`postinguser` = '5' OR find_in_set('5',p.`redwabled`)) AND (date_time < '2016-08-19 12:31:12') order by date_time desc LIMIT 20
```

So that it selects only the finalised collated rows with a `date_time` under `2016-08-19 12:31:12`. This would exclude `id: 316` in this example (which has a p.time under but it's r.time is higher). However right now I just get an 'unknown column' error message, presumably because the column doesn't actually exist.

Could someone find a way of doing this?

For reference this is an image of the other table:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that `date_time` is an *alias*, and MySQL evaluates the `WHERE` clause before this alias may exist.

You have two options here.  You can either move the `CASE` expression into the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (p.postinguser = '5' OR find_in_set('5',p.redwabled)) AND
      CASE r.redwabledby WHEN '5'
                         THEN r.time < '2016-08-19 12:31:12'
                         ELSE p.time < '2016-08-19 12:31:12'
      END
```

Or, you can use the alias `date_time` as is directly in a `HAVING` clause.  That is, use the following `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses:

```
WHERE (p.postinguser = '5' OR find_in_set('5',p.redwabled))
HAVING date_time < '2016-08-19 12:31:12'
```

The reason you can use `date_time` in a `HAVING` clause is that this clause is evaluated *after* aliases are computed.  Typically, `HAVING` applies a filter to each group in an aggregation query.  But, since you did use `GROUP BY`, the `HAVING` clause will apply to every record.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't consider moving the expression (probably wasn't sure if it would work there). I'm still learning I guess. Will try it out and get back to approve answer.